# Relevance of intermediate value theorem for showing inverse function is defined?

Tags: calculus

in this proof of how a function being strictly increasing on an interval entails that its inverse function is defined on the same interval, the intermediate value theorem is invoked. I am not exactly understanding why it is necessary here and what additional information it gives us. Using the definition of strictly increasing, we can see that the function is one to one. How does the intermediate value theorem help prove that the inverse function exists?
thanks
[image]

Comment: The inverse function is not defined on the "same interval." It is defined on the range of the function. The intermediate value theorem means that the range is also an interval, if the function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You need to argue that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is defined on the interval $[\alpha,\beta]$. Given any $\gamma\in (\alpha,\beta)$, why is $f^{-1}(\gamma)$ defined? Well, $f^{-1}(\gamma) = c$ for the unique $c\in [a,b]$ with $f(c)=\gamma$. Why are we guaranteed $c$ exists? Ah, by the Intermediate Value Theorem.